# iPhone AVAudioPlayer stopping background music

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

So I've just noticed that on my iPod Touch, when my app triggers a short wav file to play using AVAudioPlayer, the music gets paused. Is this normal?

I can't find any reference to this, and it seems like it would be noted somewhere. Is there a way to keep the music going while I play my sounds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Note**: [The AudioSession API has been completely deprecated in iOS 7.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/)

You can't run AVAudioPlayer and the iPod player or MPMusicPlayer or MPMoviePlayer at the same time, without doing a bit more work.  If you want easy, then use Audio Toolbox's System Sounds.

If you want to do some extra work, then you should look at [Audio Sessions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html):

> `kAudioSessionCategory_UserInterfaceSoundEffects`
>   For sound effects such as touch
>   feedback, explosions, and so on.
>
> Equivalent to the
>   `kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound`
>   category, which you should use
>   instead. The
>   `kAudioSessionCategory_UserInterfaceSoundEffects`
>   category is deprecated in iPhone OS
>   3.0.
>
> `kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound` For
>   long-duration sounds such as rain, car
>   engine noise, and so on. It is also
>   for “play along” style applications,
>   such a virtual piano that a user plays
>   over iPod audio.
>
> When you use this category, audio from
>   built-in applications, such as the
>   iPod, mixes with your audio. Your
>   audio is silenced when the Ring/Silent
>   switch is set to silent or when the
>   screen locks.

Answer (score 84):

Basically, every app is assigned an audio session which is modelled as a singleton class which you can get at application launch and set parameters to. The way I fixed the same problem was through a single line of code placed at `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

**Objective-C:**

```objectivec
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```

**Swift 2/3:**

```swift
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's to the point and answer's the OP's specific question

Comment: Awesome! This worked great for my SpriteKit game. Thanks!

Comment: Swift5: try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 equivalent:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, playing system sounds might not be enough, take a look at the session options, e.g. MixWithOthers

```
struct AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions : OptionSetType {
    init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
    static var MixWithOthers: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions { get }
    static var DuckOthers: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions { get }
    static var AllowBluetooth: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions { get }
    static var DefaultToSpeaker: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions { get }
    static var InterruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions { get }
}
```

When you start your session, pass the `MixWithOthers` option, maybe the `DuckOthers` (will drop the ipod volume when your sound plays) is another option.