# iOS AVAudioPlayer makes other app's background music stopped

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an exercise app which needs to play sound. I use AVAudioPlayer to play the sound.
But when the audio starts to play, the background music from another app (radio streaming app) is shutdown.

How can I make it not interrupt the background music? Because I'd like the user to hear music while doing exercise.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone AVAudioPlayer stopping background music](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672602/iphone-avaudioplayer-stopping-background-music)

Comment: you need to use a different type of audio session

Answer (score 26):

You can use the following code where you use AVAudioPlayer:

```
    // Set AudioSession
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&sessionError];
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&sessionError];
```

If you wish to set a delegate, you can add this line of code:

```
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Do you really need to set the delegate. It should be enough to set the category.

Comment: I have tested the code and only a call to setCategory is needed. Changed the sample code accordingly.

Comment: When audio from other apps played in background, my app would crash with the reason: 'required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()'. This solved that issue.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent stopping other audio that's playing when my app is opened if I'm using the playback category?

Comment: @vikzilla check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25152431. It may help you.

Comment: I open my app , music from background app stopped. below solutions is not working for me [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil]; guys any suggestion help? above solution is working when we do not use any AVAudioPlayer or AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I wanted the background audio to be played at a lower volume, as the sound played by my app is more like an alert. I use this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // prevents our app from stopping other audio,
    // e.g. music, podcats, etc. that may be playing when launched
    // our audio will be played at a higher volume
    // and the background audio will "duck" until done
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute 
                                     withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers
                                           error:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on SujithPt's Answer here is the same thing in swift:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4.2

```
import AVFoundation

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.2, add this anywhere before you play or preparetoplay:

```
_ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```