# Preventing my app's audio from interfering with other background music

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I think what I'm looking for is the combination of existing settings that I can't quite put together in the right order. I have an app that plays sound clips using AVAudioPlayer. There is a start/stop button.

I would like any other apps' audio to continue until my app actually needs to play something.

When my app is launched with some iTunes music playing, that music continues correctly. When I press play in my app, the other audio correctly stops, and my app plays. I stop my player, switch back to the music app, and press play again. But now when I switch back to my own app, the music stops immediately.

I would like it to again wait until it needs to play something before killing the music app.

My best guess is that once I've used the player, it is in some kind of 'I need audio' state, and remains in that state. How do I resign this state?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122363/iphone-app-allow-background-music-to-continue-to-play

Comment: This question is not applicable here.