# How to create a loop under the AppDelegate on Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code under the AppDelegate.m

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        NSLog(@"PLAY SOUND CLIP WHILE LOADING APP");
        NSURL *clip = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"project" withExtension:@"m4a"];
        self.startipPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clip error:NULL];
        [self.startipPlayer play] 
}
```

This only plays the audio once and not repeat. How do I make this code repeat itself or repeat the song at least?

Or any alternatives to create play background music than can loop would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: p.s. missed a trailing semi-colon at the last line ?

Comment: @Raptor, yes I know but you get the idea right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone app allow background music to continue to play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122363/iphone-app-allow-background-music-to-continue-to-play)

Comment: Yes, I do. Instead of using `AVAudioPlayer`, it's better to use `AVAudioSession` whenever possible, see the quoted duplicate question's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/numberOfLoops), it appears to have property numberOfLoops, which, if set to negative number, repeats the song indefinitely until you call stop.

Probably something like this (untested):

```
NSURL *clip = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"project" withExtension:@"m4a"];
self.startipPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clip error:NULL];
startipPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
[self.startipPlayer play]
```

Comment: How exactly do I write this? I've also looked in the documentation but I'm not sure on how to write it.