# Record Audio from another app playing in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a way to record audio that's playing in the background from another app. For example, being able to record what Pandora/Spotify is playing.

From what I understand this isn't possible yet Snapchat's latest update supports background audio when recording a video.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122363/iphone-app-allow-background-music-to-continue-to-play/14122449#14122449) shows how to allow audio to continue in the background  however as soon as I set `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];` the background audio stops immediately.

How does Snapchat allow the background audio to continue while recording?

Answer (score 2):

When initializing `AVCaptureSession` set its property:

```
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
       ...
    session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Before starting your video recording, set your `AVAudioSession` category:

```
if ([AVAudioSession sharedInstance].category != AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord) {
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker |  AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers) error:nil];
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}
```