# Prevent muting of background audio when using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation, avplayer

I am playing a video using an instance of AVPlayer and I want to be able to continue listening to background music while playing the video.

If any background app is playing music, the music is muted whenever I call `play` on the AVPlayer. How can I prevent background audio from being muted?

Here's how I create and start my AVPlayer:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
[self.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

// mutes all background audio
[player play];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14122449/4475605

Comment: That worked. Pretty hard to find though if the problem is isolated to AVPlayer

Comment: I knew exactly where to go because I encountered the same problem. Glad you're squared away.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by doing the following in the AppDelegate.swift class:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch {

    }
    return true
}
```

I also verified that if I began playing another song through iTunes it would interrupt my background playback, which is the behaviour I wanted.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for long time. I am able to play spotify music with video and audio in my app. However I preferred using AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers instead of AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback.

Answer (score 2):

Ron Allan answer unfortunately didn't work for me, however it pointed me in the right direction.  What I needed to use was the `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` category.

This is what worked for me (in AppDelegate.swift):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Don't mute the audio playback
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    } catch {}
    return true
}
```