# Play sound in background using AVAudioPlayer without stopping ipod music

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

In my app at particular time i am alerting user with beep sound which i am  playing using `AVAudioPlayer`.

Now i want this sound to be played even when app is in **background**. So i can achieve this by setting `AVAudioSession` category as `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and i also want that this sound should not stop the ipod music and i can do it with it setting `AVAudioPlayer` category `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`.

But i want them together means sound should also play in background and it should also not stop the ipod music.

So how can i achieve this?

If it is not possible to play sound with `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` category in background then any other workaround this?

Apologies if i am doing any mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: pleae take a look this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619794/play-music-in-the-background-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: You can't have the background playback without stopping the iPod music (or any other background playing app).

Comment: @Unnati may I know if you have found a solution to this? I have the similar request as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

you need to add one row in your project.plist file `Required background modes` like bellow image and set it.

[image]

and put bellow code in to your project appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        //Handle error
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
              } else {
                  // Yay! It worked!
              }
```

its working for me hope its useful for you my frnd al the best.

**UPDATE**

You can't run AVAudioPlayer and the iPod player or MPMusicPlayer or MPMoviePlayer at the same time, without doing a bit more work. If you want easy, then use Audio Toolbox's System Sounds.

please refer this bellow link:-

[iPhone AVAudioPlayer stopping background music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672602/iphone-avaudioplayer-stopping-background-music)

Please check bellow Link there are demo of Playing audio file in background. please check it

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/

Comment: You can't run AVAudioPlayer and the iPod player or MPMusicPlayer or MPMoviePlayer at the same time,